Developing with docker and vscode, sometimes the intellisense works sometimes it doesn't
I created two modules under the same project, in the first module, the Junit test functions has a little "play" or "success" icon
picture 1
but I created another module, but the Junit test intellisense doesn't work at all
picture 2
And I'm pretty sure there's a junit dependency in pom.xml, cause the vscode didn't report an error, have you ever encountered this kind of error?
Any help as well as hint will be appreciated.
thank you

If you're using docker, ensure that you've set docker.enableDockerComposeLanguageService to true. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/3222#issuecomment-924341194

Hi nick jchn, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)

@MingJie-MSFT, sorry I consused this question with another one I had before, I have posted and accepted the answer as you said, thx for the reply

It turns out that I have so many maven modules in this project, vscode needs some time to import all  of them and figure out the dependencies
my project modules picture
there will be notifications in the bottom status bar, only after all the modules have been resolved and imported that vscode extensions will then start to work

Secondly, sometimes you need to close and reopen your vscode when you just created a new project or module inside your workdir for your vscode to resolve it

Thirdly, using docker images from https://mcr.microsoft.com/ (which is the official image repository of microsoft) may provides more stability or consistency working with vscode as IDE
